# Software Signing

Tags: android, security, code-signing

I am new to software security, but so far reading about software signing on Android, I understand software signing is useful to prevent someone from injecting code inside your code. The user of the software can compare the software hash with your signature using your signature's public key, and if they don't match so the software is altered.

What I don't understand is how this really ensures protection using self signing software. What prevents someone from changing my software, injecting his code inside it, taking my self signed signature off, and making a brand new one on top of it? this way this new signature will say that everything is ok with the software and I will only find it out IF I have access to the modified software right? Or is it there something that I am not understating about the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What prevents someone from changing my software, injecting his code inside it, taking my self signed signature off, and making a brand new one on top of it?

Nothing.

> I understand software signing is useful to prevent someone from injecting code inside your code

No. Signing an app is only really for two scenarios:

1. Confirming that App A and App B were signed by the same key (and hence are from the same developer, presumably)
2. Confirming that App A and the firmware were signed by the same key

Comment: What's the advantage of case 2? Which scenario will it be used?

Comment: @mFeinstein: Both are for `signature`-level permissions, mostly. Apps can only hold `signature`-level permissions if they are signed by the same signing key that signed the app/firmware that defined the permission. Many Android permissions (e.g., `DEVICE_POWER`, for low-level power control) can only be held by apps signed by the same signing key that signed the firmware.

Comment: so basically only the developer who made the ROM I guess?

Comment: @mFeinstein: Yes, either the device manufacturer or the independent ROM mod distributor (e.g., CyanogenMod).

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have been very helpful :)